# Packing struct in Boost Asio buffer

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm looking for a way to send a packet made of a custom data structure through a socket with Boost Asio. At the moment I understand that you can send a string with the standard boost asio buffer (in the method boost::asio::write(..) ).

Is it possible to, for example, send the data from a filled in struct to the server or to a client? If yes, how do I need to do that because I can't find documentation about this.

Comment: @AndrewBarber lol @ closing this question - I don't fully agree it's too broad per se (it's tagged [tag:boost-asio] after all, and mentions he knows how to use _boost asio `buffer`_). My answer links to the parts of the documentation he couldn't find. But I see what you're missing - context and sample code :)

Comment: @sehe Hmmm... sure, I see that. Reopening!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just copy POD objects bitwise.

In fact, Asio accepts boost/std `array<T, N>`, `T[]` or `vector<T>`  buffers as long as T is a POD struct.

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/buffers.html
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html for the various constructors for mutable/const buffer sequence wrappers.

Otherwise, you could use Boost Serialization to serialize your data.

Finally, there's some support for binaries (binary dwords (big-endian/little-endian), binary floats) in Boost Spirit.

**Update** Example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
    struct { float a, b; } arr[10];

    auto mutable_buffer = boost::asio::buffer(arr);
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/edf1e845642ca97b)**

Comment: So for example could I use a newly created struct as the buffer? If I have the following: `struct {
float pos;
float pos2;
}`

Comment: So, is it possible to directly say: n bytes from pointer p? Or is that copy mandatory?

Comment: There is no copy if you use `boost::asio::buffer(...)`. **EDIT** added an example live on coliru

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Protocol Buffers for that purpose, not hard in configuring

https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

Answer (score 0):

here is some example which works for me:

```
void callback(STRUCT_A& s)
{
  f_strand.post(boost::bind(f, boost::asio::buffer(&s, sizeof(s))));
}

void f(boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1 v)
{
  STRUCT_A *a = boost::asio_buffer_cast<STRUCT_A*>(v);
}
```