# boost asio buffer to data

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868875/packing-struct-in-boost-asio-buffer) I found a way to convert a data into a boost buffer:

```
#include <memory>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
    struct { float a, b; } data1;

    auto mutable_buffer = boost::asio::buffer(data);
}
```

How to do the other way? I mean converting `recv_buf.data()` into `data1`?

```
  socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf),
      remote_endpoint, 0, error);
  data1=recv_buf.data() ???????
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pack like this:

```
struct object{ float a, b; } data1[1];
auto mutable_buffer = boost::asio::buffer(data1);
```

and unpack using `memcpy`, but only for POD types.

```
const char* b = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(mutable_buffer);
object o;
memcpy(&o, b, boost::asio::buffer_size(mutable_buffer));
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a84a6e200d706827)

Comment: I keep on seeing usage of `memcpy()` for this kind of task (on several other SO related questions). I just can't understand why Modern C++ (C++11 and next ones) doesn't provide a cleaner way to do this !

Comment: Just a note, `buffer_cast` has been deprecated since boost 1.66, and `data()` should be used in the future like so: `const char* b = mutable_buffer.data();`